# How to install OS specific python module using setup.py?

Tags: python, macos, installation, python-requests

If there a way to add specific python modules for certain OS at runtime for my python module distributed through pip ?
I want to install requests[security] module only for OS X dist and not for other Windows/Linux. Is there a way to do this in some setup script ?